# centos8 - error installing php74

Tags: centos, php7

I am a newbie in Linux. While trying install PHP-7.4 on CentOS 8 by instruction in https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/, I get error `Unable to resolve argument php:remi-7.4` at command  `dnf module install php:remi-7.4`

On CentOS PHP-7.3.22 is already installed. Please help.

```
Unable to resolve argument php:remi-7.4
No match for package php-cli
Unable to resolve argument php:remi-7.4
No match for package php-common
Unable to resolve argument php:remi-7.4
No match for package php-fpm
Unable to resolve argument php:remi-7.4
No match for package php-mbstring
Unable to resolve argument php:remi-7.4
No match for package php-xml
Error: Problems in request:
broken groups or modules: php:remi-7.4, php:remi-7.4, php:remi-7.4, php:remi-7.4, php:remi-7.4
```

Comment: What was the complete output from the command?

Comment: All output I listed in question

Comment: Well, have you run `dnf module reset php`? This is a required step, whether you have PHP already installed or not.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem with a fresh install of CentOS 8.  First, I had to add the EPEL 8 repo

```
sudo dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm -y
sudo dnf install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-8.rpm -y
```

Then disable all options for all php versions, then enable the repo for remi-7.4, specifically.

```
sudo dnf module reset php -y
sudo dnf module install php:remi-7.4 -y
sudo yum install yum-utils -y
```

After that, you can do

```
sudo yum install php
```

and it will install php from the only php repo avaialble (remi-7.4).

For reference:
https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2019/12/03/Install-PHP-7.4-on-CentOS-RHEL-or-Fedora

Comment: PHP 7.4 is in the CentOS 8 repos so one can just `yum install php` without having to use Remi.

Comment: Indeed, remi is only required for older versions (7.2, 7.3) or newer versions (8.0, 8.1) or if for additional extensions (sodium, oci8, imagick, redis, memcache...)

Comment: I don’t know what to tell you guys.  If it was working the way you guys say it should, then I wouldn’t have needed to do all the steps above.  But, it didn’t work the way you said it does, so I did follow those instructions to get PHP7.4 installed on my system.